# Golang | Assign a pointer to a pointer receiver not working

Tags: go

I do not understand why a pointer receiver is not updated when being assigned a pointer to another object.
Here is an example:

- Get is an exported getter,
- get is unexported,

I want Get() to return a pointer to an object, contained in a map of pointers indexed by strings.

I do not get why the pointer receiver of the get() method is not updated.

I tried different strategies with almost the same result each time: dereferencing, using & instead of * in variables declarations...

Go playground here: https://play.golang.org/p/zCLLvucbMjy

Any idea ?
Thanks !

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyCollection map[string]*MyType
type MyType struct {
    int
}

var collection MyCollection

func Get(key string) *MyType {
    var rslt *MyType
    // rslt := &MyType{}: gives almost the same result
    
    rslt.get(key)
    fmt.Println("rslt:", rslt) // Should print "rslt: &{2}"
    return rslt
}

func (m *MyType) get(key string) {
    m = collection[key]
    // *m = collection[key] : cannot use collection[key] (type *MyType) as type MyType in assignment
    fmt.Println("get m:", m) // Should print "get m: &{2}"
}

func main() {
    collection = make(map[string]*MyType)
    collection["1"] = &MyType{1}
    collection["2"] = &MyType{2}

    m := &MyType{1}
    m = Get("2")
    
    fmt.Println("final m", m) // Should print "final m: &{2}"
}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/zhsC9PR3kwc -- The thing you missed is the dereferencing of the value read from the map, i.e. `*m = *collection[key]` instead of `*m = collection[key]`. And note that you can't do the same with `var rslt *MyType` inside `Get` because such a `rslt` is `nil` and then doing `*m` inside `get` would panic.

Comment: Thanks mkopriva this indeed solves the problem ; I still don't get why it compils, and why this gets so complicated with dereferencing...when I just want to manipulate the adresses :/
Thanks tho !

Comment: *"I do not get why the pointer receiver of the get() method is not updated."* -- Because the receiver is a copy of the caller's variable, without dereferencing it you're just updating a completely separate variable. https://play.golang.org/p/um3JLjzSPrD (and note that each call gets its own copy)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I missed the info that the receiver was a copy each time. Could you please post this as an answer so I can close the question ? THanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dereference the receiver and assign to it a dereference value from the map, i.e. `*m = *collection[key]`.

Make sure that before you call `rslt.get` the variable `rslt` is initialized and *not* `nil`, e.g. `rslt := &MyType{}`.

```golang
func Get(key string) *MyType {
    rslt := &MyType{}
    
    rslt.get(key)
    fmt.Println("rslt:", rslt) // Should print "rslt: &{2}"
    return rslt
}

func (m *MyType) get(key string) {
    *m = *collection[key]
    fmt.Println("get m:", m) // Should print "get m: &{2}"
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/zhsC9PR3kwc

---

Note that the reason `m = collection[key]` isn't enough is because the receiver is *always* a copy of the caller's variable. And assigning to the receiver directly will just update that copy and not change the caller's variable. To update the data to which both, the receiver and the caller's variable, point to, you have to dereference the variable. And note that each call gets its own copy.

https://play.golang.org/p/um3JLjzSPrD